# Override CDN CSS with my own

Tags: css, cdn

What is the best way to override CSS rules from a CDN stylesheet?

For example, I want text decoration on all anchored text would I just use:

```
a{text-decoration: underline !important;}
```

Since bootstrap has:

```
a{text-decoration: none;}
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: In your case, you just need to use `a { /* your style here */ }`. Just load it after the cdn stylesheet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there's usually a better way when the alternative is to use `!important`. Use higher [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity). In other words, make your selector more specific so that it overrides the Bootstrap selector. For example, `body a{text-decoration: none;}`

Per the linked article:

> **Instead of using !important**, you consider:
>
> - Making better use of CSS cascading properties
> - Using more specific rules. By indicating one or more elements before the element > you're selecting the rule becomes more specific and gets higher priority

Only use `!important` when there is absolutely no other option.

Answer (score 4):

There's no need for `!important` with a selector like that. Just make sure your rules come *after* bootstrap's rules and you'll be fine.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//bootstrap.cdn.url.wow.css">
<style>
  a {
    text-decoration: underline;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: I think the same. but completely confused because of other high rep user answers here :/

Comment: @Mr_Green If the specificity is equal, then yes, loading your CSS rules after Bootstraps will prevail

Comment: Yeah. I completely disagree with @Michael_B's answer.

Comment: @j08691's answer is great but there's no reason to use more specificity here when you have control over source order.

Comment: @BillCriswell thanks. The reason I advocate specificity is that it will win out regardless of where you load it, and there are plenty of times that users can't load one stylesheet after another.

Answer (score 3):

When dealing with CDN stylesheets (which I do a lot) a safe and reliable option for overriding their rules with your own is to use `!important`.

Yes, you can go all out with specificity tricks and cascade sorcery. But ultimately, you're complicating your code, making it difficult to understand and maintain and, most important, not always ensuring your rules will prevail.

If `!important` were to exist for one reason, I think this would be it: To override CDN and other third-party styles over which you have no control.

---

**EDIT** (after a bit of backlash ;-)

This question may be focused exclusively on the Bootstrap CDN. The other answers  may satisfy that case. I don't use Bootstrap.

My experience with third-party CSS involves mostly embedded tools, such as search, translation, video and slide shows.

Those programs don't always load stylesheets in the same order. So relying on the cascade is not a good solution.

Sometimes a CDN selector is already "maxed-out" for specificity. Here's an example from the Google Translate widget:

`#goog-gt-tt .translate-form .activity-form input.activity-submit.focus #goog-gt-tt .translate-form .activity-form input.activity-submit:active`

Adding specificity to that selector is possible, but makes the code even more complex and difficult to understand.

Also important: third-parties can change selector specificity at any time, forcing you to adjust yours.

For these reasons, I normally download a copy of the CDN stylesheet and make adjustments with `!important`.

(Adding `!important` also helps distinguish your styles from the CDN's when checking dev tools.)

Comment: Teach me something new, downvoter. As I mentioned, I do this a lot. If you have a more efficient and effective method, I'm honestly all ears.

Comment: [Not the downvoter] Can't we just load our stylesheets after the cdn to override the styles? that works for normal stylesheets so I am assuming that it should also work for CDN. I don't think loading from CDN matters though.

Comment: Your rules would still need to be equal or higher specificity.

Comment: Using the same specificity level in other stylesheet  which is loading after the CDN, automatically overrides CDN's styles. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: If two selectors are loaded with equal specificity, the latter one prevails. If two selectors are loaded with different specificity, the higher specificity one prevails, regardless of the cascade.

Comment: My point is the same. Instead of using `!important`, if we just load our stylesheet after the CDN ones then our styles i.e the latter one will prevail.

Comment: Also, I don't use Bootstrap, which seems to be the focus of this question. Other answers may satisfy the Boostrap case. My issues have been with third-party CSS for many embedded tools such as search, translation, videos and slide shows. Specificity and cascade have *not* been reliable. Try that approach with Google Search or Google Translate. Only `!important` worked for me.

Comment: How are "Specificity and cascade have not been reliable."? They're just rules. If they didn't work for you at some point then perhaps you didn't get the specificity correct? It's not like browsers indiscriminately apply selectors.

Comment: @j08691 Here's how: In many cases, the selectors are ridiculously long already. For me to override them would require making them even longer. Second, third-party CSS selector specificity often changes. Then I have to adjust my specificity, as well.

Comment: Again, this is probably not a Bootstrap issue. But after dealing with scores of online widgets and tools, the only efficient, effective and reliable method I've found is to use `!important`. Can I bend over backwards to make specificity and cascade work? Probably in some cases. By what's wrong with `!important`? This seems like the perfect use-case for it.

Comment: @Mr_Green, added more details to my answer. Hope it resolves your confusion.